# Crossing from Russia to Alaska, no US visa

Tags: usa, russia

I am living in Afghanistan and I would like to immigrant to Alaska,
here it is possible to get the Russia visa but I would like to know: is there any way to leave Russia and get to Alaska?  I don't have a visa for the USA.

Also, I have plan a trip from Alaska to Canada.

Can you please let me know which way this is possible, if at all?

Comment: Come up with a new idea - that plan is going to get you killed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for help with an illegal activity.

Comment: I have edited your question for clarification.  Please let me know if it is still an accurate description of your situation.

Comment: Russia and the US do not have any border in common, there's no way to cross like you envision.  Both sides are extremely inhospitable terrain, even if there was a border in common you probably wouldn't survive the trip.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for advice on how to execute illegal behavior.

Answer (score 9):

**Impossible.**

Unless you are [extremely well trained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Bushby), it is not possible to travel between Russia and Alaska without taking regular, scheduled flights.  You will not be able to board those flights without a US visa.

As an alternative, I would recommend [cycling from Russia to Norway](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-34602208).  Many refugees from Syria and Afghanistan have discovered this route.  Take the train to Murmansk, then <s>train</s>¹ bus to [Nikel](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nikel), then ride a bicycle to the [Storskog border crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storskog) where you can seek refugee status (travelling on foot is not allowed and hitch-hiking will get the driver into trouble, but taxis reportedly can bring you to 100 metre from the border).  Note that it will soon be winter and temperatures well below -20°C are quite possible, so you might want to wait until spring (that means June).

---

¹Apparently, passenger trains to Nikel have been cut.

Comment: (+1) Interesting and I don't doubt your info but I am wondering why hitch-hiking would get the driver in trouble. If the person seeks asylum *at the border* (i.e. does not try to enter irregularly), I don't see why it should be a problem. Does Norwegian law really prohibit this?

Comment: @Gala According to local (Norwegian) media reports, Norwegian border police treat it as human-smuggling when someone brings a refugee to the border / attempts to bring it across the border.  Not sure about the details.

Comment: @gerrit presumably, crimes of human smuggling requires accepting payment, abusing the smuggled person, or the like.  Giving someone a ride should not qualify as human smuggling.  For example, the US [defines](http://www.acf.hhs.gov/programs/orr/resource/fact-sheet-human-trafficking#TraffickingVSmuggling) human smuggling as "the illegal transport of an individual across a national border. Smuggling is always transnational."  Taking someone *to* the border would not qualify as a crime under this definition.

Comment: @phoog Go ahead and discuss that with the Norway police/court when they use Norwegian rather than US law after deciding to prosecute you ;-) All I know is that they *warn* drivers not to take migrants/refugees and that this warning appears to be taken seriously by drivers (Norwegians are quite law-abiding). I don't know if any case actually did proceed to court.